# fetch data from web services

Tags: php, joomla

I am fetching data from web services its displaying 25 result from a page once time is there any way to limit the result.Means I want to display 5 result once time anyone know how it is possible.

Comment: Are you using joomla database object for fetching data?

Comment: How is the data coming? csv, xml, json? In any case, loop over the results and show only that much you want to display. Rest can come on "More results" kind of stuff.

Comment: share some of your code and show your effort

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this programatically? Or through some kind of Joomla 'thing' ?

If programatically, its as easy as pie!

```
$count = 0;
$limit = 5;
foreach ($result as $item) {
  // Display your item
  if ($count++ >= $limit) {
    // If we hit the limit, we'll bow out of the loop.
    break;
  }
}
```

It'd be better if you could just request 5 items from the service, but if this isn't possible and you're only getting 25 (and not 2500!) then this will be fine.